# Why NoClassDefFoundError when launching BlueJ?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, bluej

I am a student trying to learn Java, and I am starting a course from Coursera which requires me to install a custom version of BlueJ. I followed the instructions, which said I need JDK 1.8 or higher. I checked this with the command `javac -version`, which printed:

```
javac 11.0.12
```

And the command `java -version`:

```
java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237, mixed mode)
```

I have assumed that this is all correct based on what it requires from me, so I proceeded to install the program with the command `sudo dpkg -i BlueJ-linux-411-duke.deb` (This is the link to the instructions I used: https://www.dukelearntoprogram.com//downloads/bluej.php?course=2)

Now, after BlueJ is installed, I tried running the program from it's icon but nothing happened. It doesn't launch, and no error is shown in any way. So I went to the terminal and I wrote `bluej` which prompted this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at bluej.Boot.main(Boot.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 13 more
```

I have googled this error but all the answers seem to talk about actual projects that they have running on their compilers, whereas here I'm just trying to open the program. I have tried reinstalling and basically everything I could think of. I'm pretty new to Linux, I'm using Linux Mint 20.1 (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).

How can I fix this? I'm completely out of options. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't got to the bottom of this JavaFX stuff myself, but I've found that it's problematic with anything over 1.8. I've just taken the easy way out and used it only with that version, using Bellsoft's JDK in Debian Linux. This is what I do: `alias j8='export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java8-full-amd64;export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'`. If you did that then started BlueJ, my bet would be that you'd be OK. I simply do `j16` when I want non-JavaFX operation

Comment: Sounds like this application was written for Java 8 (which included JavaFX), JavaFX has since been unbundled, and it is now the responsibility of the application to bring it in. Either run it on Java 8, or find out of there is a newer version that supports Java 11 (and thus includes JavaFX itself).

Comment: BTW, your download link explicitly states that _"You must use version 1.8.x for this course."_

Comment: @g00se thank you for the reply! I want to try to do what you explained but I'm not sure how to. What you posted looks like the Java environment, which I usually access with `sudo nano /etc/environment`, but I'm not sure if that's what you meant.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it seems I didn't read it properly, that's my bad! I went back to those versions but the problem persists. `java -version` now prints `openjdk version "1.8.0_292"` and `javac -version` prints `javac 1.8.0_292`. But I still get the same error, I thought it would've been fixed as it shows the correct version, so now I really am out of ideas

Comment: `echo $JAVA_HOME` prints `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle`. I have tried changing that, and I thought I had successfully changed it with `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"`. I used the `source /etc/environment` command and verified it and it printed `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`, but when I close the terminal and open it again, it prints again `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle`. I'm not sure if that's relevant, but I thought I'd mention it

Comment: *I want to try to do what you explained but I'm not sure how to.* You're Debian-based distro might well have the file `~/.bash_aliases`. If so, that's the place for your aliases. Otherwise ~/.bashrc. Don't forget to *source* ~/.bashrc when you make any changes for them to be placed into the environment